# Mysql Query is selecting only the first row instead of all.

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I would like to ask if somebody can help me resolve this issue with a Mysql Query which Barmer helped me build. but what it occurs the query is selecting only one row of data, the first one in the table.

```
SELECT c.*, count(s.curso_id) as count, SUM(IF(s.status = "aprobado", 1, 0)) AS count_approved , SUM(IF(s.status = "cupolleno", 1, 0)) AS count_cupolleno
, SUM(IF(s.status = "cancelado", 1, 0)) AS count_cancelado, SUM(IF(s.status = "noacion", 1, 0)) AS count_noacion, SUM(IF(s.status = "ama_de_casa", 1, 0)) AS count_ama_de_casa
, SUM(IF(s.status = "cliente_externo", 1, 0)) AS count_cliente_externo
FROM cursos_modulos AS c
LEFT JOIN subscriptions AS s ON s.curso_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.userID = s.user_id
```

What I need is to select all the rows from cursos_modluos right now is selecting only one. If somebody can let me know where the possible fix of this I would appreciate it very much!

Comment: As I can see, you are missing the GROUP BY statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using aggregation functions with no `group by`.  Such a query always returns exactly one row.

It is not clear what you want to do, but I might guess that adding:

```
GROUP BY c.id
```

would do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
SELECT c.*, count(s.curso_id) as count, SUM(IF(s.status = "aprobado", 1, 0)) AS count_approved , SUM(IF(s.status = "cupolleno", 1, 0)) AS count_cupolleno
, SUM(IF(s.status = "cancelado", 1, 0)) AS count_cancelado, SUM(IF(s.status = "noacion", 1, 0)) AS count_noacion, SUM(IF(s.status = "ama_de_casa", 1, 0)) AS count_ama_de_casa
, SUM(IF(s.status = "cliente_externo", 1, 0)) AS count_cliente_externo
FROM cursos_modulos AS c
LEFT JOIN subscriptions AS s ON s.curso_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.userID = s.user_id
GROUP BY c.id <<----
```